# snapshot of overlay image from array of images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, overlay, augmented-reality

I have multiple images under scrollview. When i click one image it will displays overlay image of camera overlay view. But when i click button it won't take snapshot of camera overlay image. I take reference from http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1681#comment-37185

code:

```
- (void)ButtonPressed {

[self captureStillImageWithOverlay:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"], nil]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably use `UIImagePickerController`. It returns original camera image without overlay, so you have to add overlay yourself, and position it correctly.